# Stopping a thread in Android is deprecated

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on an Android project and  I have a thread which is posting to a PHP API and does checks with the response.

Before the thread starts I show a progress dialog which can be cancelled. When the cancel is pressed I call `thread.stop()` but this shows up as deprecated.

Everything I have found on Google suggest that I have a flag and check the flag within the while loop and come out of the thread cleanly, however in my circumstances there is no loop, so how should I go about doing this?

Comment: You should probably be using AsyncTask, rather than threads.

Comment: "I call thread.stop() but this shows up as deprecated" -- `stop()` has been deprecated in Java for the better part of two decades. [Try `interrupt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29).

Comment: It is not deprecated in Android, it is deprecated in java.

Comment: use Thread.interrupt();

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is know problem because, [threads are not supposed to be stopped by calling](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4nYYxKN084wC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=discourage%20Java%20Threads%20in%20Android&source=bl&ots=RzEwbZULIo&sig=DFOzxg7qXE72gRyHmNXeG3uKhk8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirg9qOysLMAhVHv44KHUOOA80Q6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=discourage%20Java%20Threads%20in%20Android&f=false) `thread.stop();` method.

Also Android discourages the use of Java Threads in Android, and Conveniently, Android has some additional support for when it comes to communicating between Threads, The Handler class provides a neat queued message mechanism, and Looper provides a handy method for processing same.

But as you mentioned you want to show a progress dialog which can be cancelled. When the cancel is pressed, so this type of functionality can be achieved using `AsyncTask`.

As `AsyncTask` is one of the easiest ways to implement parallelism in Android without having to deal with more complex methods like `Threads`. 
Though it offers a basic level of parallelism with the UI thread, it should not be used for longer operations (of, say, not more than 2 seconds).

> Mainly AsyncTask should handle your problem, Since:
>
> 1. It provides easy and standard recommended mechanism to publish background progress (see the **Usage** section here:
>      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
> 2. It provides method cancel(boolean); for cancelling a task(see the **Cancelling a task** section here:
>      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask has four methods to do the task:

```
onPreExecute();
doInBackground();
onProgressUpdate();
onPostExecute();
```

And `cancel();` method to handle the cancellation of the background work.

Where doInBackground() is the most important as it is where background computations are performed.

**Code:**
Here is a skeletal code outline with explanations:

```
public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        // This starts the AsyncTask
        // Doesn't need to be in onCreate()
        new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1);
    }

    // Here is the AsyncTask class:
    //
    // AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>.
    //    Params – the type (Object/primitive) you pass to the AsyncTask from .execute() 
    //    Progress – the type that gets passed to onProgressUpdate()
    //    Result – the type returns from doInBackground()
    // Any of them can be String, Integer, Void, etc. 

    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
 }
}
```

For more in depth knowledge visit following links:

https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, AsyncTask semms like a lot of overhead